# Write a loop using python

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I need to print value with some size using condition.

```
size, url
1 https://api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com/user_guid?
3257 https://init.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZInit.woa/wa/signSapSetupCert
0 http://engine.rbc.medialand.ru/code?
35 http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
0 http://engine.rbc.medialand.ru/test?
0 http://engine.rbc.medialand.ru/code?
```

I get it in loop and I try to get all `url`, where `size` more than 43.

```
if not size:
    continue
elif size[0] < 43:
    continue
else:
    print size[0], url
```

`If` condition works, but `elif` doesn't. It print all `size` and `url`

Comment: Are you reading this from a file? If then the issue can be with the string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, which you are using, strings can be compared to integers. Strings always compare as being larger than integers.

```
>>> '35' < 43
False
```

To solve this, wrap the string in an `int()` call:

```
>>> int('35') < 43
True
```

For your program:

```
elif int(size[0]) < 43:
```